# How to write first class functions with context bounds, that can be called cleanly at use site?

Tags: scala, scalaz, typeclass

For example, let us say I want to write a function `length` that returns length of the given structure, given that it has an instance of type class `Length` (from Scalaz) in scope.

This is how I currently define it:

```
scala> def length[A, F[_] : Length]: F[A] => Int = _.len
length: [A, F[_]](implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Length[F])F[A] => Int
```

However a call such as `length(List(2, 3))` fails because in this case the implicit parameter is the first argument required.

```
scala> length(List(2, 3))
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scalaz.Length[?]
              length(List(2, 3))
                         ^
```

I thought `length(implicitly)(List(2, 3))` would work, but it ends up crashing the sesssion (which is understandable as type inference flows from left to right). Providing an explicit type annotation works, but it's unbearably ugly.

```
scala> length(implicitly[Length[List]])(List(2, 3))
res16: Int = 2
```

Is there a good way to write a first class function such as `length`, having a context bound, which can be called as cleanly as regular functions at the use site? (like `length(List(2, 3))`)

Comment: `length[Int, List].apply(List(2, 3))` is arguably slightly nicer.

Comment: Also, in terms of motivation, is this just an exercise, or is there some reason the straightforward method version (`def length[A, F[_]: Length](xs: F[A]): Int = xs.len`) won't work for you?

Comment: @TravisBrown: No, this is not just an exercise. I am actually looking to use it (crazy?).

Comment: @TravisBrown: The explicit eta expansion with `(_)` looks ugly, and most of the times requires type annotations. For example, `((_: List[Int]).sum) &&& ((_: List[Int].length))`. I'd like to make it `sum &&& length`.

Comment: I sincerely hope Scala type inference gets more powerful in the near future; the number of type annotations required for such simple things is just ridiculous. You'd think that `def length = _.len` would be sufficient. One could even hope that `len` would be automatically lifted as a first class function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy, cheat!

```
scala> def length[A, F[_] : Length]: F[A] => Int = _.len
length: [A, F[_]](implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Length[F])F[A] => Int

scala> List(2, 3) |> length
res0: Int = 2
```

Comment: Damn! :-D Why didn't I think of it!

Comment: Still sucks with generic programming. Can't compose. :-(